# Sonar CeWorkerRunnableImpl - Failed to execute task AVKxZzs3XOSwYL28ZL1g

Tags: sonarqube

Facing nullpointerexception while integrating jenkins(1.646) and sonar(5.2).

I am trigerring jenkins job for sonar scan, which is completing sucessfully.

```
INFO] Analysis reports generated in 17987ms, dir size=9 MB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 21186ms, zip size=3 MB
[INFO] Analysis reports sent to server in 1029ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://10.72.118.177:9000/dashboard/index/com.barclaycard.bpay.core:bPay_Core
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
[INFO] More about the report processing at http://10.72.118.177:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVKxZzs3XOSwYL28ZL1g
```

**However when I look at the status on sonar it I'm getting the below error -**

```
016.02.05 12:28:52 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Failed to execute task AVKxZzs3XOSwYL28ZL1g
java.lang.NullPointerException: null key in entry: null=org.sonar.server.computation.sqale.SqaleRatingSettings$LanguageSpecificConfiguration@1a17df9
    at com.google.common.collect.CollectPreconditions.checkEntryNotNull(CollectPreconditions.java:31) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.entryOf(ImmutableMap.java:135) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.put(ImmutableMap.java:206) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.sqale.SqaleRatingSettings.buildLanguageSpecificConfigurationByLanguageKey(SqaleRatingSettings.java:54) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.sqale.SqaleRatingSettings.<init>(SqaleRatingSettings.java:46) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace reports an unexpected corruption of the configuration of the debt by language.

Please look at the admin page located in Administration > Technical Debt.

In the section "Language specific parameters", it's very likely you have an empty language key such as below:

[image]

Ticket [SONAR-7154](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7154) has been created to better handle this.